# how to bind a string with mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using some mat-checkbox in my app and i do not know how to receive a string from the checkbox instead a boolean.

Reading the API in the website
[Angular Material checkbox API](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api) 
 I could find the 'value' propertie that can assing a string to this checkbox... but how can i bind this to my variable?

I am trying something like this.

```
<mat-checkbox color="warn" value="Hello" [(ngModel)]="myString"> Hello </mat-checkbox>
```

but my variable is getting a boolean... how can i do it?

Comment: It seems strange to get a string from a checkbox. If it's disabled, what value do you get ? Null ?

Comment: no, the variable is just a empty string, ""

Comment: finally `checked` attribute could only be true/ false

Answer (score 2):

Binding the the checkbox's ngModel will always return it's checked state (true / false / indeterminate). If you want to get the `value` property from the checkbox you could add an change event to the element like so

```
<mat-checkbox color="warn" value="Hello" [(ngModel)]="myString"  (change)="onChange($event)"> Hello </mat-checkbox>
```

and in your component ts

```
onChange(event: any)
{
  console.log(event.source.value); // will contain "hello"
  console.log(event.source.checked); // will contain the checked state of the checkbox
}
```

Comment: so... is not possible to bind the variable directly to the value? uhm...

Comment: i was expecting that it would has an easy solution... because in my case i have a form with at least 10 checkbox...

Answer (score 2):

All the checkbox in my backend receive 'Y' or 'N', so I had to do this:
Remove [(ngModel)] and create a function for all checkBox

```
<mat-checkbox name="active" [checked]="model.active === 'Y'" (change)="checkboxChange($event);" > Click me </mat-checkbox>
```

component.ts

```
checkboxChange( event ){
   let name = event.source.name;
   this.model[name] = event.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name property to store the string value instead of the ngModel.

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isChecked"                                                                                    
       name="{{checkboxStringValue}}">//make sure name is unique for every item
        </mat-checkbox>
```